# Главное слово в СПП

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, от какого слова задаётся вопрос в СПП, если в главной части имеется соотносительное слово, - от глагола "начал" или местоимения "с того"?

***Прокуратор начал с того, что пригласил первосвященника на балкон…*** (М.Булгаков)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Прокуратор начал **с того, что** пригласил первосвященника на балкон…*

Это СПП **с приместоименным изъяснительным** придаточным (вмещающие СПП). Такие придаточные занимают промежуточное положение  между изъяснительными и приместоименными.

Как  и в изъяснительных придаточных, опорным словом здесь является знаменательное слово (**глагол** в данном случае), а в качестве связи используется **союз** (а не союзное слово).

Но вот соотносительное слово  (с того) является **обязательным** элементом, причем оно образует **единый блок с придаточным.**

Итак, начал (с чего?) – с того, что пригласил первосвященника на балкон…

Comment: Я так поняла, знак × будет над соотносительным словом  в схеме предложения?

Comment: Я полагаю, что знак должен всегда стоять над ОПОРНЫМ словом (начал), так как именно от него мы задаем вопрос. Соотносительное слово тоже может быть ОПОРНЫМ, но в местоименно-соотносительных предложениях, например: Я принес ТО, ЧТО вы хотели. Здесь ЧТО - союзное слово, а не союз, местоименная пара ТО - ЧТО. Можно задать вопрос: ЧТО именно? - ЧТО вы хотели.